# Open div on hover in same div

Tags: html, css

I was given this image:

[image]

The left side is a menu that opens on hover and the right side is a menu that opens within the menu when you hover over a menu item.

My question is, can I achieve this with pure CSS?

In theory:

- Hover navbar, it opens the left menu
- Hover an item in the right menu it does the same thing

It'd be like this

```
<li class="first-level-menu-item has-submenu">
                            <a href="#money">Money</a>

                            <!-- Render second level -->
                            <div class="second-level">
                                <div class="second-level-header">
                                    <p class="second-level-heading">Money</p>
                                    <p>More than just investment, we are a trusted partner to support and empower the management team to deliver the next phase of growth.</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="second-level-menu">
                                    <p>FINANCE OPTIONS</p>

                                    <ul class="second-level-menu-items">
                                        <li class="second-level-menu-item">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M14 12.5H2C1.86739 12.5 1.74021 12.4473 1.64645 12.3536C1.55268 12.2598 1.5 12.1326 1.5 12C1.5 11.8674 1.55268 11.7402 1.64645 11.6464C1.74021 11.5527 1.86739 11.5 2 11.5H14C14.1326 11.5 14.2598 11.5527 14.3536 11.6464C14.4473 11.7402 14.5 11.8674 14.5 12C14.5 12.1326 14.4473 12.2598 14.3536 12.3536C14.2598 12.4473 14.1326 12.5 14 12.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 14H3C2.86739 14 2.74021 13.9473 2.64645 13.8536C2.55268 13.7598 2.5 13.6326 2.5 13.5C2.5 13.3674 2.55268 13.2402 2.64645 13.1464C2.74021 13.0527 2.86739 13 3 13H13C13.1326 13 13.2598 13.0527 13.3536 13.1464C13.4473 13.2402 13.5 13.3674 13.5 13.5C13.5 13.6326 13.4473 13.7598 13.3536 13.8536C13.2598 13.9473 13.1326 14 13 14Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M1 8.5H0.5V10C0.5 10.2652 0.605357 10.5196 0.792893 10.7071C0.98043 10.8946 1.23478 11 1.5 11H3V10.5C2.99942 9.96974 2.78852 9.46137 2.41357 9.08643C2.03863 8.71148 1.53026 8.50058 1 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 7.5H15.5V5.5H15C14.2046 5.49909 13.4421 5.18273 12.8797 4.62032C12.3173 4.0579 12.0009 3.29537 12 2.5V2H4V2.5C3.99909 3.29537 3.68273 4.0579 3.12032 4.62032C2.5579 5.18273 1.79537 5.49909 1 5.5H0.5V7.5C0.65625 7.5 0.823125 7.5 1 7.5C1.79537 7.50091 2.5579 7.81727 3.12032 8.37968C3.68273 8.9421 3.99909 9.70463 4 10.5V11H12V10.5C12.0009 9.70463 12.3173 8.9421 12.8797 8.37968C13.4421 7.81727 14.2046 7.50091 15 7.5ZM8 9.5C7.40666 9.5 6.82664 9.32405 6.33329 8.99441C5.83994 8.66476 5.45542 8.19623 5.22836 7.64805C5.0013 7.09987 4.94189 6.49667 5.05764 5.91473C5.1734 5.33279 5.45912 4.79824 5.87868 4.37868C6.29824 3.95912 6.83279 3.6734 7.41473 3.55764C7.99667 3.44189 8.59987 3.5013 9.14805 3.72836C9.69623 3.95542 10.1648 4.33994 10.4944 4.83329C10.8241 5.32664 11 5.90666 11 6.5C10.9991 7.29537 10.6827 8.0579 10.1203 8.62032C9.5579 9.18273 8.79537 9.49909 8 9.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M8 8.5C9.10457 8.5 10 7.60457 10 6.5C10 5.39543 9.10457 4.5 8 4.5C6.89543 4.5 6 5.39543 6 6.5C6 7.60457 6.89543 8.5 8 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 10.5V11H14.5C14.7652 11 15.0196 10.8946 15.2071 10.7071C15.3946 10.5196 15.5 10.2652 15.5 10V8.5H15C14.4697 8.50058 13.9614 8.71148 13.5864 9.08643C13.2115 9.46137 13.0006 9.96974 13 10.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 4.5H15.5V3C15.5 2.73478 15.3946 2.48043 15.2071 2.29289C15.0196 2.10536 14.7652 2 14.5 2H13V2.5C13.0006 3.03026 13.2115 3.53863 13.5864 3.91357C13.9614 4.28852 14.4697 4.49942 15 4.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M3 2.5V2H1.5C1.23478 2 0.98043 2.10536 0.792893 2.29289C0.605357 2.48043 0.5 2.73478 0.5 3V4.5H1C1.53026 4.49942 2.03863 4.28852 2.41357 3.91357C2.78852 3.53863 2.99942 3.03026 3 2.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mr-auto">Newable Capital</div>
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M5.75 3.5L10.25 8L5.75 12.5" stroke="#9D9D9D" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="second-level-menu-item">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M14 12.5H2C1.86739 12.5 1.74021 12.4473 1.64645 12.3536C1.55268 12.2598 1.5 12.1326 1.5 12C1.5 11.8674 1.55268 11.7402 1.64645 11.6464C1.74021 11.5527 1.86739 11.5 2 11.5H14C14.1326 11.5 14.2598 11.5527 14.3536 11.6464C14.4473 11.7402 14.5 11.8674 14.5 12C14.5 12.1326 14.4473 12.2598 14.3536 12.3536C14.2598 12.4473 14.1326 12.5 14 12.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 14H3C2.86739 14 2.74021 13.9473 2.64645 13.8536C2.55268 13.7598 2.5 13.6326 2.5 13.5C2.5 13.3674 2.55268 13.2402 2.64645 13.1464C2.74021 13.0527 2.86739 13 3 13H13C13.1326 13 13.2598 13.0527 13.3536 13.1464C13.4473 13.2402 13.5 13.3674 13.5 13.5C13.5 13.6326 13.4473 13.7598 13.3536 13.8536C13.2598 13.9473 13.1326 14 13 14Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M1 8.5H0.5V10C0.5 10.2652 0.605357 10.5196 0.792893 10.7071C0.98043 10.8946 1.23478 11 1.5 11H3V10.5C2.99942 9.96974 2.78852 9.46137 2.41357 9.08643C2.03863 8.71148 1.53026 8.50058 1 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 7.5H15.5V5.5H15C14.2046 5.49909 13.4421 5.18273 12.8797 4.62032C12.3173 4.0579 12.0009 3.29537 12 2.5V2H4V2.5C3.99909 3.29537 3.68273 4.0579 3.12032 4.62032C2.5579 5.18273 1.79537 5.49909 1 5.5H0.5V7.5C0.65625 7.5 0.823125 7.5 1 7.5C1.79537 7.50091 2.5579 7.81727 3.12032 8.37968C3.68273 8.9421 3.99909 9.70463 4 10.5V11H12V10.5C12.0009 9.70463 12.3173 8.9421 12.8797 8.37968C13.4421 7.81727 14.2046 7.50091 15 7.5ZM8 9.5C7.40666 9.5 6.82664 9.32405 6.33329 8.99441C5.83994 8.66476 5.45542 8.19623 5.22836 7.64805C5.0013 7.09987 4.94189 6.49667 5.05764 5.91473C5.1734 5.33279 5.45912 4.79824 5.87868 4.37868C6.29824 3.95912 6.83279 3.6734 7.41473 3.55764C7.99667 3.44189 8.59987 3.5013 9.14805 3.72836C9.69623 3.95542 10.1648 4.33994 10.4944 4.83329C10.8241 5.32664 11 5.90666 11 6.5C10.9991 7.29537 10.6827 8.0579 10.1203 8.62032C9.5579 9.18273 8.79537 9.49909 8 9.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M8 8.5C9.10457 8.5 10 7.60457 10 6.5C10 5.39543 9.10457 4.5 8 4.5C6.89543 4.5 6 5.39543 6 6.5C6 7.60457 6.89543 8.5 8 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 10.5V11H14.5C14.7652 11 15.0196 10.8946 15.2071 10.7071C15.3946 10.5196 15.5 10.2652 15.5 10V8.5H15C14.4697 8.50058 13.9614 8.71148 13.5864 9.08643C13.2115 9.46137 13.0006 9.96974 13 10.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 4.5H15.5V3C15.5 2.73478 15.3946 2.48043 15.2071 2.29289C15.0196 2.10536 14.7652 2 14.5 2H13V2.5C13.0006 3.03026 13.2115 3.53863 13.5864 3.91357C13.9614 4.28852 14.4697 4.49942 15 4.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M3 2.5V2H1.5C1.23478 2 0.98043 2.10536 0.792893 2.29289C0.605357 2.48043 0.5 2.73478 0.5 3V4.5H1C1.53026 4.49942 2.03863 4.28852 2.41357 3.91357C2.78852 3.53863 2.99942 3.03026 3 2.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mr-auto">Newable Capital</div>
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M5.75 3.5L10.25 8L5.75 12.5" stroke="#9D9D9D" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="second-level-menu-item">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M14 12.5H2C1.86739 12.5 1.74021 12.4473 1.64645 12.3536C1.55268 12.2598 1.5 12.1326 1.5 12C1.5 11.8674 1.55268 11.7402 1.64645 11.6464C1.74021 11.5527 1.86739 11.5 2 11.5H14C14.1326 11.5 14.2598 11.5527 14.3536 11.6464C14.4473 11.7402 14.5 11.8674 14.5 12C14.5 12.1326 14.4473 12.2598 14.3536 12.3536C14.2598 12.4473 14.1326 12.5 14 12.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 14H3C2.86739 14 2.74021 13.9473 2.64645 13.8536C2.55268 13.7598 2.5 13.6326 2.5 13.5C2.5 13.3674 2.55268 13.2402 2.64645 13.1464C2.74021 13.0527 2.86739 13 3 13H13C13.1326 13 13.2598 13.0527 13.3536 13.1464C13.4473 13.2402 13.5 13.3674 13.5 13.5C13.5 13.6326 13.4473 13.7598 13.3536 13.8536C13.2598 13.9473 13.1326 14 13 14Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M1 8.5H0.5V10C0.5 10.2652 0.605357 10.5196 0.792893 10.7071C0.98043 10.8946 1.23478 11 1.5 11H3V10.5C2.99942 9.96974 2.78852 9.46137 2.41357 9.08643C2.03863 8.71148 1.53026 8.50058 1 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 7.5H15.5V5.5H15C14.2046 5.49909 13.4421 5.18273 12.8797 4.62032C12.3173 4.0579 12.0009 3.29537 12 2.5V2H4V2.5C3.99909 3.29537 3.68273 4.0579 3.12032 4.62032C2.5579 5.18273 1.79537 5.49909 1 5.5H0.5V7.5C0.65625 7.5 0.823125 7.5 1 7.5C1.79537 7.50091 2.5579 7.81727 3.12032 8.37968C3.68273 8.9421 3.99909 9.70463 4 10.5V11H12V10.5C12.0009 9.70463 12.3173 8.9421 12.8797 8.37968C13.4421 7.81727 14.2046 7.50091 15 7.5ZM8 9.5C7.40666 9.5 6.82664 9.32405 6.33329 8.99441C5.83994 8.66476 5.45542 8.19623 5.22836 7.64805C5.0013 7.09987 4.94189 6.49667 5.05764 5.91473C5.1734 5.33279 5.45912 4.79824 5.87868 4.37868C6.29824 3.95912 6.83279 3.6734 7.41473 3.55764C7.99667 3.44189 8.59987 3.5013 9.14805 3.72836C9.69623 3.95542 10.1648 4.33994 10.4944 4.83329C10.8241 5.32664 11 5.90666 11 6.5C10.9991 7.29537 10.6827 8.0579 10.1203 8.62032C9.5579 9.18273 8.79537 9.49909 8 9.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M8 8.5C9.10457 8.5 10 7.60457 10 6.5C10 5.39543 9.10457 4.5 8 4.5C6.89543 4.5 6 5.39543 6 6.5C6 7.60457 6.89543 8.5 8 8.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M13 10.5V11H14.5C14.7652 11 15.0196 10.8946 15.2071 10.7071C15.3946 10.5196 15.5 10.2652 15.5 10V8.5H15C14.4697 8.50058 13.9614 8.71148 13.5864 9.08643C13.2115 9.46137 13.0006 9.96974 13 10.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M15 4.5H15.5V3C15.5 2.73478 15.3946 2.48043 15.2071 2.29289C15.0196 2.10536 14.7652 2 14.5 2H13V2.5C13.0006 3.03026 13.2115 3.53863 13.5864 3.91357C13.9614 4.28852 14.4697 4.49942 15 4.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                    <path d="M3 2.5V2H1.5C1.23478 2 0.98043 2.10536 0.792893 2.29289C0.605357 2.48043 0.5 2.73478 0.5 3V4.5H1C1.53026 4.49942 2.03863 4.28852 2.41357 3.91357C2.78852 3.53863 2.99942 3.03026 3 2.5Z" fill="#4D4E5E"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mr-auto">Newable Capital</div>
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
                                                    <path d="M5.75 3.5L10.25 8L5.75 12.5" stroke="#9D9D9D" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

My question is: how do I handle the third menu?

Here's what this code blob looks like for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something similar to this ?

[image: Example]

Create the  sub-list inside the "li" element and give the "li" and "ul" a unique id

```html
<div class="header">
        <ul class="header__list1">
          <li class="header__list1--item">Home</li>
          <li class="header__list1--item">About us</li>
          <li class="header__list1--item" id="money">
            Money<svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="16"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              fill="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M5.75 3.5L10.25 8L5.75 12.5"
                stroke="#9D9D9D"
                stroke-width="1.5"
                stroke-linecap="square"
              ></path>
            </svg>
            <ul class="header__list2" id="money-list">
              <li class="header__list2--item" id="newable_capital">
                Newable Capital<svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="16"
                height="16"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                fill="none"
              >
                <path
                  d="M5.75 3.5L10.25 8L5.75 12.5"
                  stroke="#9D9D9D"
                  stroke-width="1.5"
                  stroke-linecap="square"
                ></path>
              </svg>
                <ul class="header__list3" id="newable_capital-list">
                  <li class="header__list3--item">Why we're different</li>
                  <li class="header__list3--item">What we do</li>
                  <li class="header__list3--item">Our investments</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="header__list2--item">Business Finance</li>
              <li class="header__list2--item">Property Finance</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Use the id for the event listeners in order to show the list that corresponds to the list item, example: `#money:hover #money-list`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__list1 {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.header__list1--item,
.header__list2--item,
.header__list3--item {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.header__list1--item {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.header__list2--item {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #adadad;
}
.header__list3--item {
  background-color: #8b8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #adadad;
}
.header__list2, .header__list3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
.header__list2 {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.header__list3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
#money:hover #money-list {
  display: block;
}
#newable_capital:hover #newable_capital-list {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain what this piece is of code is doing so that the OP can understand

Comment: Hi both, this is very close to my goal yes, can I ask how specifically you went about this?

Comment: @JesseLukeOrange I added explanation to my answer, I hope you find them useful.